# Linear Regression without Sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression

I am trying to write a class LinearModel, representing a linear regression model. it gives an error for def predict

```
class LinearModel:
    def __init__(self, X, y):
        self.X = X
        self.y = y
        #X columns of 1s appended on its left,
        X = np.vstack((np.ones((X.shape[0], )), X.T)).T
        
        if len(self.X)!=len(y):
            raise ("they are not similar")

    def fit(self):
        # stores this coefficient vector in the object.
        Xt = np.transpose(X)
        XtX = np.dot(Xt,X)
        Xty = np.dot(Xt,y)
        beta = np.linalg.solve(XtX,Xty)
        self.fit = beta
        
     
    def coef(self):
       # raise an error if called before the model has been fitted

        if not self.fit:
            raise ValueError("Need to call the fit function first")

        #returns βˆ.
        return self.fit

    
    def predict(self,X0=None): # Takes an optional argument X0
           
        if not self.fit:
            raise ValueError("Need to call the fit function first")
        if X0==None:
            X0 = X
        X0 = np.vstack((np.ones((X0.shape[0], )), X0.T)).T

        # where X0 is X0 with column of 1s added on its left. 
        prediction = self.fit * X0  # method should return X0 * βˆ 
        return prediction



X = np.array([[-1.34164079, -1.25675744], [-0.4472136, -0.48336824],
                          [0.4472136, 0.29002095], [1.34164079, 1.45010473]])
y = np.array([1, 3, 4, 6])
model = LinearModel(X, y)
model.fit()
print(model.coef())
print(model.predict())
```

**edits**

```
class LinearModel:
    def __init__(self, X, y):
        self.X = X
        self.y = y
        #X columns of 1s appended on its left,
        X = np.vstack((np.ones((X.shape[0], )), X.T)).T
       
        
        if len(self.X)!=len(y):
            raise ("they are not similar")

        self._is_fitted : bool = False

    def fit(self):
        
        Xt = np.transpose(X)
        XtX = np.dot(Xt,X)
        Xty = np.dot(Xt,y)
        beta = np.linalg.solve(XtX,Xty)
        beta_array = np.array(beta)
        self.fit = beta_array
        self._is_fitted = True
        
        
     
    def coef(self):
       # raise an error if called before the model has been fitted

        if not self._is_fitted:
            raise ValueError("Need to call the fit function first")

        #returns βˆ
        return self.fit

    
    def predict(self,X0=None): # Takes an optional argument X0
           
       
        if not self._is_fitted:
            raise ValueError("Need to call the fit function first")
        if X0==None:
            X0 = X
        X0 = np.vstack((np.ones((X0.shape[0], )), X0.T)).T
        # where X0 is X0 with column of 1s added on its left. 
        prediction = np.multiply(X0, self.fit)  # method should return X0 * βˆ 
        return prediction
        


X = np.array([[-1.34164079, -1.25675744], [-0.4472136, -0.48336824],
                          [0.4472136, 0.29002095], [1.34164079, 1.45010473]])
y = np.array([1, 3, 4, 6])

model = LinearModel(X, y)
model.fit()
print(model.coef())
print(model.predict())
```

> it gives an error of ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,3) (2,) meaning that I will have to to broadcasting to multiply 2 matrices. Can anymore suggest me how?

Comment: It would help if you tell us which line the error occurs on. i.e. add the stack trace

Comment: Some advice :
- Don't give the same names to methods and attributes
- Don't check for exceptions if you're going to calculate it either way, just calculate it.
- Don't add "format" elements to data that you are using.

Comment: RE edit: Assigning to `beta` and `self.beta` is not the same thing. `beta` is a local variable, and not preserved across method calls. `self.beta` is an instance variable, and it is preserved.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can't use a method name as an attribute. Is `self.fit` supposed to be a method to fit? Or the coefficients?
2. You can't test if that attribute (let's call it `beta`) is assigned simply by saying `if self.beta` or something similar. First of all, if it is not, you'll get an error for trying to read an unassigned variable. Secondly, and that is the error you get, if that `beta` contains something that is neither True nor False, you'll get an error about Truth value. So, assign a value to `beta` in the `__init__` method. For example `self.beta=None`. And then test if it is `None` with `if beta is None`.
3. All attributes access must be prefixed with `self.`. You are using `X` instead of `self.X` more than once. Which means that those `X` are the global one. The one to which you haven't added a column of `1`.
4. `self.beta * X0` is not doing what you expect to do. `*` is a member×member multiplication, not a matrix multiplication (and if it were a matrix multiplication it would be an illegal one). `@` (or `.dot`) is the matrix multiplication operator. And to multiply a 3×n matrix by a 3 elements vector, you need to do it the other way. So `X0 @ self.beta`
5. [Non fatal] There is a `np.hstack` function, rather than `vstack + double transpose`.